# Rename files in sub directories using sub directory name with incremental number restarting for each sub directory

Tags: batch-file, rename

I have a few directories, named "A", "B", "C", and so on. Each has some files in it. I like to rename files in each directory using directory name plus an index number starting with 1 in each directory, with left-zero padded to the width of 3. For example:
Sub directory A has 3 files, and they'll be renamed as:

```
A_001.dat
A_002.dat
A_003.dat
```

Sub directory B has 2 files, and they should be renamed as:

```
B_001.dat
B_002.dat
```

and so on. These files will be moved to the main directory. I have the following batch file, but I can't seem to increment the number. Please help.

```
@echo off

set HomeFolder=%CD%
set OldExt=TXT
set NewExt=DAT

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.%OldExt% /b /s') do (
    set i=1
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
        set pad=00!i!
        set str=!pad:~-3!
        echo move /b "%%a" "%HomeFolder%\%%~nxb_!str!.%NewExt%"
        set /A i=!i!+1
)
)
endlocal
pause
```

And the correct answer is:

```
@echo off

set HomeFolder=%CD%
set OldExt=TXT
set NewExt=TIF
set i=1
set Folder=
set LastFolder=

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.%OldExt% /b /s') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
        set Folder=%%~nxb        
        if NOT !Folder!==!LastFolder! (set /A i=1)
        set LastFolder=!Folder!
        set pad=00!i!
        set str=!pad:~-3!
        copy /b "%%a" "%HomeFolder%\%%~nxb_!str!.%NewExt%"
        Set /A i+=1
    )
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

In a loop or parenthetical expression you need to use a delayed expansion

set /a variable=!variable!+1

But you need to activate this feature with setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and reset it with a matching endlocal

Try the following:

```
@echo off

set HomeFolder=%CD%
set OldExt=TXT
set NewExt=DAT

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.%OldExt% /b /s') do (
set i=1
for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
    set pad=00%i%
    set str=%pad:~-3%
    echo move /b "%%a" "%HomeFolder%\%%~nxb_%str%.%NewExt%"
    set /A i+=1
)
)

endlocal

pause
```

Comment: Tried it, did not work, results are the same

    move /b "C:\Test\A\001.txt" "C:\Test\A_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\A\002.txt" "C:\Test\A_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\A\003.txt" "C:\Test\A_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\A\004.txt" "C:\Test\A_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\B\001.txt" "C:\Test\B_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\B\002.txt" "C:\Test\B_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\B\003.txt" "C:\Test\B_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\B\004.txt" "C:\Test\B_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\B\005.txt" "C:\Test\B_.DAT"
    move /b "C:\Test\C\001.txt" "C:\Test\C_.DAT"
    Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You enabled delayed expansion, but didn't use it. `%var%` is immediate (normal) expansion. `!var!` is delayed expansion.

Comment: I tried the !var!, it looks better, but i does not get incremented, always stays at 1. Therefore the new name is always _001.DAT.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

:: By Elektro H@cker

Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "OldExt=TXT"
set "NewExt=DAT"

FOR /R %%@ in (*%OldExt%) DO (

    REM Sets the directory of the file
    Set "Directory=%%~dp@"

    REM Cuts the directory name to obtain the last folder name
    Set "Directory=!Directory:~0,-1!"
    For /L %%X in (0,1,50) DO (Call Set "Directory=!Directory:*\=!")

    REM Check if this directory is the same of the last accesed directory to reset the counter or not
    Echo "!Directory!"|FINDSTR "^\"!LastDirectory!\"$" >NUL && (Set /A "Count+=1") || (Set /A "Count=1")

    REM Check if the number incrementation have 1-3 digits and copies the file
    Call Echo !COUNT!|FINDSTR "^[0-9]$"    >NUL && (Call Copy "%%@" ".\!Directory!_00!COUNT!.%NewExt%")
    Call Echo !COUNT!|FINDSTR "^[0-9].$"   >NUL && (Call Copy "%%@" ".\!Directory!_0!COUNT!.%NewExt%" )
    Call Echo !COUNT!|FINDSTR "^[0-9]..+$" >NUL && (Call Copy "%%@" ".\!Directory!_!COUNT!.%NewExt%"  )

    REM Sets the last accesed directory
    Call Set "LastDirectory=!Directory!"
)

Pause&exit
```

3 subdirs named "A" "B" and "C", 3 files inside of each subdir, the output result is:

```
a_001.DAT
a_002.DAT
a_003.DAT
b_001.DAT
b_002.DAT
b_003.DAT
c_001.DAT
c_002.DAT
c_003.DAT
```

Comment: Thanks! It runs perfectly, but very SLOW. Any ideas why?

Comment: ofcourse because there is a loop that runs 50 times to split the absolute folder name into the current folder name, that cannot be done in Batch, no native method for split a var by a character. and a triple comparision is needed in the code to get the numeration incrementation that you want because in Batch you can't do this: "000"+"001"=001, and that comparisions take a lot of execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working script for whoever wants to do the same thing:

```
@echo off

set HomeFolder=%CD%
set OldExt=TXT
set NewExt=DAT
set i=1
set Folder=
set LastFolder=

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.%OldExt% /b /s') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
        set Folder=%%~nxb        
        if NOT !Folder!==!LastFolder! (set /A i=1)
        set LastFolder=!Folder!
        set pad=00!i!
        set str=!pad:~-3!
        copy /b "%%a" "%HomeFolder%\%%~nxb_!str!.%NewExt%"
        Set /A i+=1
    )
)

endlocal
```